# Cassandra cqlsh - datastax windows community edition - USE command error

Tags: cassandra

When I use below command I get `Bad Request: Keyspace 'ks_test' does not exist`, any help? I do see this keyspace from opscenter.

```
USE ks_test;

Bad Request: Keyspace 'ks_test' does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to see a list of your keyspaces:

```
DESC KEYSPACES;
```

Also, if you type `USE` and then hit tab then cqlsh should list all of the valid keyspace names.

It's possible that the keyspace is not named `ks_test`, but rather some case sensitive name like `KS_test`, in which case you need to quote the name, like this:

```
USE "KS_test";
```